# Add if case for checking values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to improve the this code by adding if or switch case:

Original code:

```
           {(errorMessage || invalidEmailError.length > 0) && (
            <Message type="error" className="mt-l">
              {`If an account exists` || invalidEmailError}
            </Message>
          )}
```

I want to change `Message type="error"` to `Message type="success"` so I tried this:

```
      {invalidEmailError.length > 0 && (
        <Message type="error" className="mt-l">
          {invalidEmailError}
        </Message>
      )}
      {errorMessage && (
        <Message type="success" className="mt-l">
          {`If an account exists `}
        </Message>
      )}
```

If it possible to use if or switch case here so I can improve the code?

Comment: If you use class components, you can create a switch case in the render function before you return the template. There you can assign the message template to a variable and use it in your return template

Answer (score 0):

I think [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) may help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes you show me how I can use switch case, please?

Comment: Not sure you can use `switch ... case` inside JSX.

Comment: ok, other better solutions?

Comment: Ternary: `<Message type={errorMessage ? "error" : "success"} className="mt-l">`

Comment: Can you show me full code example, please?